# .hide() not working after appendTo

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following code which works fine on IE8:

```
$("<div class='divButtons'>").appendTo( $(".widget_header") );
$(".divButtons").html( "(close), (min), (max)" );
```

However, if I add a `.hide`, instead of just hiding `.divButtons`, it hides the whole `.widget_header`.

For example:

```
$("<div class='divButtons'>").appendTo( $(".widget_header") );
$(".divButtons").html( "(close), (min), (max)" ).hide();
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: @NullPointer how is this a duplicate? OP is running the `.hide()` after appending the element, which is just fine.

Comment: You should use `.text(…)` rather than `.html(…)` if you don't want your text to be parsed as HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't closing your div tag and so your HTML will be invalid, causing the bounds of all of your divs to become skewed. Try this instead:

```
$("<div class='divButtons'></div>").appendTo( $(".widget_header") );
$(".divButtons").html( "(close), (min), (max)" ).hide();
```

This is a documented IE8 issue that you can read about [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12581)

Further to this, you can create more concise, optimized code by doing the following:

```
$("<div class='divButtons'>(close), (min), (max)</div>").appendTo( $(".widget_header"));​
```

And using css to hide it initially in the form of `display: none;`

Here's a [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abRfG/) of it

Comment: Seems at least unlikely to be cause IMO as jQuery will not simply thrown the html there, it will parse the string into DOM element(s) then append it. Anyway providing a valid HTML is good practice.

Comment: OP mentions IE8 which needs closing tags in appendTo, see [this issue](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12581)